# 7 segment LED + 4094

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, avr, led

I would like to display 2 number usig two shift registers 4094, some 7 segment LED and an ATmega 328p.
My curent code is:

```
uint8_t LED[10]={0b11111100,0b01100000,0b011011010,0b011110010,0b01100110,0b10110110,0b10111110,0b111000000,0b11111110,0b11110110};


int j =Led; //input from the main
uint8_t num_1=Led/10;
uint8_t num_2=Led%10;       
Strobe=0;
uint8_t mask=0x80;
 for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
      mask=mask>>1;     

    if( (LED[num_1]  & mask) ==1)
    {
        DATA= 1;
    }
    else
    {

        DATA= 0;
    }
    pulse();
}
mask=0x80;
for(uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    mask=mask>>1;
     ;

    if( (LED[num_2]  & mask)==1)
    {
        DATA= 1;
    }
    else
    {

        DATA= 0;
    }
    pulse();
}
```

But of course it does not work properly.  It generates only 0.
Can you point me in the right direction?
EDIT:
I use Atmel studio 6.
The purpose of the code is to generate number from 00 to 16.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Is the goal to generate some bit pattern or a sequence of bit patterns? The code looks like C, is it actually C?

Comment: The 4094 requires an extra signal to store the shifted-in values into its internal register which stores its output. I don't see you taking care of that (between shifting out the two digits).

Comment: If you show code, you should tag language. Besides helping people find the question, it also affects the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shoud put `mask = mask>>1` in the end of loop.

Second, you need to replace the
`if( (LED[num_2] & mask) ==   1 )` with
`if( (LED[num_2] & mask) == mask)` or just
`if(  LED[num_2] & mask )`

Mask could be 0b10000000, 0b01000000,...,0b00000001.
The result of `&` operation  can only be the same as mask or zero.
And the right side of `==` operator is `1`, which is always 0b00000001.

Comment: Can I get rid of the if statement and write directly Data= LED[num_2] & mask??

Comment: As I metioned before, the result of **AND** operation can be the same as mask or zero. You can do this when the resutl is zero. When the result is mask, the result would be non-zero which is not the same as **1**. According to the principle of  **4094**, the **Data** can ony be **1** or **0**.

Comment: I think the most quickly way is this **Data =  !!(LED[num_2] & mask)**. The second **!** convert the **mask(non-zero)** to **0**, or **0** to **1**. The first **!** correct the logic. I haven't think about this before until you metioned this, thank you the same.